# Many-to-one with table records requiring one another

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have two tables: Talks and Days. Talks looks something like:

```
+----+----------------------------------+--------+
| Id |               Name               | Leader |
+----+----------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | How to improve revenue for tacos | Tacob  |
|  2 | Improving sales potential        | Bocat  |
+----+----------------------------------+--------+
```

and the Days:

```
+--------+-----+
| TalkId | Day |
+--------+-----+
|      1 | Mon |
|      1 | Tue |
|      1 | Thu |
|      2 | Mon |
|      2 | Tue |
+--------+-----+
```

`TalkId` is a foreign key referencing the `Talks` table.

The foreign key enforces the relationship of "A Day requires a Talk". However, I would like to also enforce the reverse relationship "A Talk requires at least a Day".

I know that this constraint is similar to a Many-to-many relationship, where both records depend on each other. However, in this case, many days reference a talk but only one talk references many days.

Another problem is that after creating such a constraint, how would one insert both records at once?

I have searched for other questions and only found cases of Many-to-many relationships which will turn out like so:

```
+----+----------------------------------+--------+
| Id |               Name               | Leader |
+----+----------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | How to improve revenue for tacos | Tacob  |
|  2 | Improving sales potential        | Bocat  |
+----+----------------------------------+--------+

+----+-----+
| Id | Day |
+----+-----+
|  1 | Mon |
|  2 | Tue |
|  3 | Thu |
|  4 | Mon |
|  5 | Tue |
+----+-----+

+--------+-------+
| TalkId | DayId |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     1 |
|      1 |     2 |
|      1 |     3 |
|      2 |     4 |
|      2 |     5 |
+--------+-------+
```

Where `TalkId` references `Talks`'s `Id` and `DayId` references `Days`'s `Id`.

**Edit**:

Ignore what I requested for above.

What I hope to be able to do:

1. `SELECT` all valid `Talks`
2. `SELECT` all valid `Days`

What I hope to be unable to do:

1. `INSERT` a `Talk` without a `Day`
2. `INSERT` a `Day` without a `Talk`

Comment: `TalkId` is a foreign key to talks.Id in your case. Are you saying that you would like to enforce that no talks can exist without days as well?

Comment: @LordBaconPants Yes, that is the problem. It doesn't make sense that a talk never happens on any day

Comment: It is impossible for rows in both tables to be dependent upon each other in that way.  If a `A day requires at least one talk`, then you would create the `talk`(s) and then create the `day` with a reference to a `talk` record.  That way the `day` always refers to a `talk`, there is never a moment in time where it doesn't.  But if you ***also*** have `A talk requires at least one day` you can never put any records in either table.  You can't put records in two tables at once, so you have to pick one table to populate first.  But if you only populate one table, you breach one of your constraints

Comment: @MatBailie However, it is possible if I treated it as a many-to-many relationship and added another table but that would be quite excessive. See the edit

Comment: Your edit only exagerates your problem.  Now either ***one*** of your constraints stops you from populating the tables.  If `a day must be mapped to at least one talk` then you need to populate `day` as well as `day_talk`, at exactly the same time.  If `a talk must be mapped to at least one day` then you need to populate `talk` as well as `day_talk`, at exactly the same time.  But you can ***never*** populate more than one table at a time.  *(It's a perfectly valid many:many structure, it's your constraints that are the problem.)*

Comment: What might be helpful is explaining ***why*** you think you need these constraints.  You are better served re-working your processes or software to not require these constraints, because they're going to be impossible to implement.

Comment: @MatBailie Although I cannot guarantee that both tables have a Talk and a Day at the same time, I can guarantee that all records in the third table will have both relationships: A talk will have at least a day and a day will have at least a talk.

Comment: Then you need to be much clearer about your requirements, because that's not what you said in your question.  In your question you said: `any day in existence must associate to a talk, and any talk in existence must associate to a day`.  You proposed schema is perfectly valid, but enforces no constraints at all.  You can create as many days as you like, and as many talks as you like, and leave them all unrelated.  As for the guarantees made by the third table, they're not guarantees, they're observations... `a day in the day:talk mapping table is related to a talk`, well, ummm, obviously...

Comment: Please explain explicitly what you need.  Give examples of what you want to be possible, and what you want to be impossible.  And then give explanations of why you want those behaviours.  At the moment every time you write something, to clarify what you wrote previously, you end up materially changing what you're saying.

Comment: @MatBailie edited, in that case, it's impossible!

Comment: Correct.  You can `SELECT` valid talks and valid days from a multitude of different structures.  But the restrictions on the `INSERTS` are impossible.  You can have one ***or*** the other, and only if you have a one:many relationship.  If you have a many:many relationship you can't enforce ***either*** constraint.  So, I refer back to my previous question : ***why*** do you think you need these constraints?  Give examples of situations that you feel ***must*** be avoided and ***why*** you feel they must be avoided.  Then we can propose alternatives for you...

Comment: @MatBailie the main reason why is because the code used to insert data into the database will be altered as other people will be maintaining it. To reduce the likelihood of bugs, I would like to implement restrictions at the database level.

Comment: That's too vague / abstract.  What specific bugs or incorrect behaviour are you attempting to prevent?  Think about what unit tests you might write that would rely on these constraints.  Which tests would be impossible to specify without the constraints?  That tells you what bugs your constraints protect you from.  In all likelihood this is premature optimisation.  Instead of trying to prevent these situations, build in to your software an understanding that you must first create a day/talk before you can relate it to anything.  Then write tests that ensure such understanding is in place.

Comment: Some database systems allow constraint checking to be postponed until the transaction is committed.  Then, you make both updates in the context of a single transaction,  and commit.  Both constraints are satisied.  Your database system might not have such a feature.

Comment: If what you want is a circular foreign key arrangements, that is do-able. But not always desirable. There's an excellent explanation of the ins and outs here--> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102903/is-it-acceptable-to-have-circular-foreign-key-references-how-to-avoid-them

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a simple foreign key relationship:

```
alter table days add constraint fk_days_talkid foreign key (talkid) references talks(talkid);
```

This guarantees that `talkid` is valid.  Then you declare `days.talkid` to be `not null` and you are guaranteeing the relationship you describe.

Comment: I don't think this is what I meant. I would like two relationships: A Talk requires at least a Day and a Day requires a Talk. This looks like it only establishes the second relationship

Comment: @MoonCheesez . . . You have changed your question after I answered the original.  That is rude.

Comment: Sorry, that was the original problem I was facing, I changed the question to clarify myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Day named (TheDay) exists.
--
Calendar {TheDay}
      PK {TheDay}


-- Talk (TalkID) titled (TalkName), presented by (Leader) is by default
-- scheduled on (DefaultDay).

Talk {TalkID, TalkName, Leader, DefaultDay}
  PK {TalkID}
  AK {TalkName}

FOREIGN KEY {DefaultDay} REFERENCES Calendar {TheDay}


--Talk (TalkID) is also scheduled on (TheDay).
--
TalkDay {TalkID, TheDay}
     PK {TalkID, TheDay}

FOREIGN KEY {TalkID} REFERENCES Talk     {TalkID}
FOREIGN KEY {TheDay} REFERENCES Calendar {TheDay}
```

```
Note PK = primary key
     AK = alternate key (unique)
     All attributes (columns) NOT NULL
```

---

Select all days for a specific talk:

```
select TalkName, DefaultDay as TalkDay
from Talk
where TalkName = 'How to improve revenue for tacos'

union

select TalkName, b.TheDay as TalkDay
from Talk    as a
join TalkDay as b on b.TalkID = a.TalkID
where a.TalkName = 'How to improve revenue for tacos'
```

Select all talks on a specific day:

```
select TalkName, DefaultDay as TalkDay
from Talk
where DefaultDay = 'Tue'

union

select TalkName, b.TheDay as TalkDay
from Talk    as a
join TalkDay as b on b.TalkID = a.TalkID
where b.TheDay = 'Tue'
```